# How to add first 5 and last 5 records from a same dataset in a new object in Rstudio

Tags: r

This is a question about R language, I have tried me<- head(data,5)+ tail(data,5)

Answer (score 1):

`+` does element-wise sum of values in the two dataframe. You need to use `rbind` to combine the two dataframes into one.

```
me <- rbind(head(data, 5), tail(data, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest done with square brackets and the use of `nrow()`:

```
new_data <- iris[c(1:5, (nrow(iris) - 4):nrow(iris)), ]
```

Comment: Hey @mnist, the code is not working for me, I wants to add these records in a new object in Rstudio.

Comment: I updated the solution to an available dataset. There was also a typo in it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't mention name of a column in what you tried, I am assuming you want to add all columns in the dataframe. See if below code works:

```
> df <- data.frame(c1 = 1:10, c2 = 11:20)
> df
   c1 c2
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 13
4   4 14
5   5 15
6   6 16
7   7 17
8   8 18
9   9 19
10 10 20
> 
> df[1:5, ] + df[(nrow(df)-4):nrow(df), ]
  c1 c2
1  7 27
2  9 29
3 11 31
4 13 33
5 15 35
>
```